# How can I run a dotnet core asp.net application from a network drive

Tags: security, .net-core

I develop a stratight forward dotnet core asp.net application on Windows. All works fine. But if I have the very same folder from a mapped network drive, the application does not start.

Debugging with Visual Studio reveals that the program assembly is loaded, the configuration step is executed which looks like

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseUrls("http://devmachine:7777")
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

But the code in Startup.cs (usual code there) is never executed.

As said, the very same code works when not on a network share.

I used CasPol to set FullTrust on the network share but that did fix it. I wonder if dotnet core behaves similar like dotnet with respect to this security stuff. Also I think I need to configure the application to "use" CasPol, since CasPol writes that. But I do not know *what* I have to do.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running from a mapped network drive instead of using the full UNC path (i.e. `\\server\path\website`)?

Comment: @DavidG yes, from a mapped network drive.

Comment: That's a problem as mapped drives are specific to the logged in user but your app will almost certainly be running as another account. Use a proper UNC path.

Comment: thx for the clarifying hint. i will try that.

Comment: Did you succeed with the UNC approach?

Comment: Its been a while since I faced that problem. Today from a mapped drive with dotnet core 3.1 it works well.